# Hibernate 5 the value is not set for the parameter number 2

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

I'm working on a migration from **Hibernate 3** to **Hibernate 5** version. Currently, I'm using **5.4.0.Final** version.

I have a problem with one of the tests that uses a repository method **deleteByAllPatientFlowGens**:

```
public void deleteByAllPatientFlowGens(List<PatientFlowGen> list) {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(DELETE_BY_ALL_PATIENT_FLOW_GENS_QUERY)
                .setParameter("patient_flow_gens", list)
                .executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

It should call the named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = RequestedFlowGenSettings.DELETE_BY_ALL_PATIENT_FLOW_GENS_QUERY,
            query = "delete from RequestedFlowGenSettings where patientFlowGen in :patient_flow_gens")
```

The method receives the list with two elements, but in logs I see that both parameters are binding as **1**:

```
2019-03-19 04:44:16,855 DEBUG [main] SQL - delete from requested_flow_gen_settings where patient_flow_gen in (? , ?)
2019-03-19 04:44:16,858 TRACE [main] BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2994]
2019-03-19 04:44:16,858 TRACE [main] BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2995]
2019-03-19 04:44:16,864 ERROR [main] SqlExceptionHelper - The value is not set for the parameter number 2
```

With previous Hibernate version (3.6.3.Final) everything worked fine. There are logs:

```
2019-03-19 04:47:42,275 DEBUG [main] SQL - delete from requested_flow_gen_settings where patient_flow_gen in (? , ?)
2019-03-19 04:47:42,277 TRACE [main] BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 2996
2019-03-19 04:47:42,277 TRACE [main] BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 2997
```

P.S. I tried to use **setParameterList** method, but the problem was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the only way to fix the problem is to execute named query for each element from the list. So, here is my repository method:

```
public void deleteByAllPatientFlowGens(List<PatientFlowGen> list) {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        list.forEach(patientFlowGen -> {
            getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(DELETE_BY_ALL_PATIENT_FLOW_GENS_QUERY)
                    .setParameter("patient_flow_gens", patientFlowGen)
                    .executeUpdate();
        });
    }
}
```

I know, it is a quick dirty fix. But I have no choice )